# Own file extension - Double click does not handle over file path

Tags: c#

I've managed to create my own file extension following this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17023/System-File-Association

So far, it works perfectly. I've got only one thing that I can't solve.
When I double-click on a file with that extension, my program opens up. Now, I'd want to perform an action in my program. I made my way through some threads here and read that the file path is automatically passed to the startup arguments.

The problem is that no single argument is passed, also *Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartInfo.FileName* returned an empty string. I think this is consecutively because I don't pass any arguments when double-clicking my file.

This is my code:

```
var fai = new FileAssociationInfo(".extension");
if (!fai.Exists)
{
   try
   {
      fai.Create("My Extension Program");

      var pai = new ProgramAssociationInfo(fai.ProgId);
      if (!pai.Exists)
      {
          pai.Create("My Program File",
          new ProgramVerb("Open", Application.ExecutablePath);
          pai.DefaultIcon = new ProgramIcon(Application.ExecutablePath);
      }
    }
 }
```

As you can see I only pass the application's path to open it up. But how can I pass the file path as argument now? I've seen that e.g. the author of the article passes "%1" as argument, I tried that, too, but nothing changed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I got it. What I had to do was creating a subkey in ClassesRoot: "ProgramName\shell\open\command". Then set a value containing the application's path and attach "%1" to it and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

[`ProcessStartInfo.FileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.filename(v=vs.110).aspx) usually gives you the path to your program executable itself, not the file which was clicked in Windows Explorer, so this seems the wrong thing to check in your case.

If you want to get the arguments using the current `Process`, then [`Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartInfo.Arguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments(v=vs.110).aspx) should give you a string containing all the arguments passed to the program. If there are multiple arguments, you would need to parse these into separate values yourself.

But the standard, simpler way to get the arguments is to make sure the `Main()` method of your program has signature `static void Main(string[] args){}`. `args` is already processed into separate values for you, so it is easier to handle it here, even if you only pass it off to another class or store them in a static variable.

The `%1` should ensure the clicked file is passed as the first argument (`args[0]`) to your program.

Comment: The Main-method doesn't provide me any arguments, as I wrote above. Consecutively "Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartInfo.Arguments" provides me an empty string, so nothing basically.
The "%1" sounds interesting but there aren't any arguments, too.